# How to choose between base 64 and base64url encoding

Tags: java, encoding, urlencode

I have to send data over the web . Which encoding is better to use

Base64 or Base64URL ?

Comment: The only difference is only one has an alphabet that is safe for embedding in an URL. Unless you need that, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both uses alphanumeric characters for 62 of the 64 (65) characters needed for Base-64 encoding.

*Standard Base64* uses `+` and `/` for the last 2 characters, and `=` for padding.

*Base64Url* uses `-` and `_` for the last 2 characters, and makes padding optional.

So you have a choice:

- If the Base64-encoded text needs to be transmitted/saved where `+`, `/`, or `=` have special meaning, e.g. in URLs where all 3 does, then it is better to use *Base64Url*.
- If the Base64-encoded text needs to be transmitted/saved where `-` or `_` have special meaning, then it is better to use *Standard Base64*.
- If none of the 5 characters have special meaning, then you can choose whichever you want, though you should use *Standard Base64*, because it is ... the Standard, and using standards is a better choice.

Note that there are more defined variants than those two. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history) for detail.